# My routes seem setup correctly, but are generating incompatible urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My "link_to" and "url_for" etc. methods are generating paths in the pattern of ":controller/:id/:action", instead of ":controller/:action:/:id" - in other words my "action" and "id" fields in the url are getting swapped.

I've narrowed it down to these generated links through doing some route debugging, however, I don't quite understand how the routes.rb file can say one thing, but the generated routes can be in a different order. Is there something more to this than the routes file alone?

*In case it matters, I'm also using authlogic to do my user authentication.

Here's my routes.rb file, with the comments removed.

```
map.resources :tags
map.resources :ratings
map.resources :users
map.resources :bids
map.resources :listings
map.resource :user_session
map.root :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "new"
map.resource :account, :controller => "users"
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh...I might have solved my problem, though I don't know how.

The URLs still seem wrong to me, clicking on the "Show", "Edit" or "Destroy" links used to take me to an error page where I'd get a nil reference error due to the funky routes.

I just did a "rake db:migrate:redo STEP=3" after making a small change to one of my previous migrations, restarting the web server, and now the app navigates without error.

What I still don't understand though, is that the generated links are still ":controller/:id/:action", but it's suddenly it's decoding properly.

Very confused.